# Why does ROBLOX use an object-oriented system rather than an entity component system?

Tags: architecture, entity-system, design-patterns, entity-component-system, roblox

I decided I would develop a game engine in c++, so I was thinking about different ways of handling objects. I also have experience with ROBLOX, so I know that it uses an object-oriented design as opposed to an entity component system.

Here's a simplified example of how ROBLOX's system works: there's a base class called `Instance` that all objects in a place (a `DataModel` instance) inherit from. `Instance`s representing a physical object inherit from the `BasePart` class, static `Instance`s which only provide services inherit from `ServiceProvider`, and instances which exist solely to modify or contain their parent or child instances inherit from the `Instance` class itself. For example. if you add a `SpecialMesh` instance as a child of a `Part` instance, the part will be rendered using the appearance of the mesh. (there are probably some other examples I'm missing as well).

ROBLOX also allows you to modify the properties of instances directly, with the user interface grouping properties together by what things they affect, rather than providing them as traditional components. For example, a `Part` instance would have an Appearance section in the GUI properties window which shows properties like `Color`, `Material`, `Opacity`, etc.

In addition, I've worked on code for the GoldSrc and Source engines (for modding, of course), and they appear to use a very similar system.

This seems to go against a lot of what I've learned about designing systems like it, with most developers preferring to take the ECS route instead. Why did ROBLOX decide to use this object-oriented design rather than the more conventional entity component system?

Comment: We usually can't answer "why did other developer X do Y" - you'd have to ask X directly. But I think you may have been misled about how universal ECS is in games. It's been trendy in recent years, but there's still a great deal of more conventional OOP in game tech too. Sometimes it just comes down to developer preference.

Comment: @DMGregory I'd also like to add that (from what I know) most games who use ECS also use OOP as well.

Comment: Yeah, usually ECS is a subset of OOP - when folks present them as a dichotomy, they mostly mean "Using OOP in an ECS style with buffers of plain-old-data-structures" vs "Using OOP in a 'classic' style with inheritance, V-tables, and trees." A lot of game tech does a little of both - even an engine that's heavily classic OOP will look very ECS when you look at its particle system code. And even ECS heavy engines tend to look more classic OOP when it comes to UI widgets.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question. Questions about design intent of existing products [can't be answered here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), because we can only guess what the original Roblox developers thought when they built their architecture.

Comment: Object-oriented is *easier*. Much easier: one thing in the game = one object. System-oriented programming requires you to think about all the things in the game at once.